# Display Algolia Results with Jinja / Django

Tags: django, jinja2, algolia

I have got `Algolia` all set up with `Django` and the results are displaying. However, when I move on to formatting them there is a clash with the `Jinja`templating engine.

Essentially Algolia uses the double parentheses like `Jinja {{ value }}`

In the script below the `{{ highlightResult.name }}` cause a error

How do I render the results of the search without using the double parentheses?

Thanks!

```
<script>

const searchClient = algoliasearch('xxx', 'xxx');

const search = instantsearch({
  indexName: 'Item',
  searchClient,
});

console.log(search)

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: '#searchbox',
  })
);

search.addWidget(
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits',
    templates: {
      item: `
        <div>
         {{ highlightResult.name }}

        </div>
      `,
    },
  })
);

search.start();

</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you load your script as a static file?

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan Thanks! Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Using an external javascript file worked for this as the double parentheses weren't clashing with Jinja2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works

```
{% verbatim %}
    <script id="hit-template" type="text/template">
        // Django will no longer interpret `{` and `}
    </script>
{% endverbatim %}
```

And if this does not work then you have to do like this

```
<script src="{% static '/js/algolia.js' %}"></script>
```

**algolia.js**

```
const search = instantsearch({
  indexName: '<Your_Index_Name>',
  searchClient: algoliasearch('<Your Application_id>', '<Your Search API>'),
  searchFunction: function(helper) {
    if (helper.state.query.length === 0) {
        return; // do not trigger search
    }

    helper.search(); // trigger search
  }
});

search.addWidgets([
  instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
    container: '#searchbox',
  }),
  instantsearch.widgets.hits({
    container: '#hits',
    templates: {
      item: `
        <div>
          <img width="100px" height="100px" src="{{product_image_url}}" align="left" alt="{{name}}" />
          <div class="hit-name">
            {{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "model_no" }{{/helpers.highlight}}
            {{#helpers.highlight}}{ "attribute": "product_title" }{{/helpers.highlight}}
          </div>
        </div>
      `,
    },
  }),
]);

search.start();
```